# CRM workflow run another workflow

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm-4, crm

*Not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312170/running-a-workflow-from-within-another-workflow)*

I have a pretty simple CRM workflow, which basicly just adds some values to some fields that doesn't get filled whenever a user creates a new object. My challenge here is that a lot of objects are already created in CRM, with a lot of null values. We are talking thousands. So instead of asking the client to open every single object and running the workflow, I was thinking I could create a second workflow which initiates the first workflow to run on all current objects. Is this possible and how should I do it?

Comment: You should tell us what software/framework this is about.

Comment: @Mchl - Look at the updated tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the workflow execution. Its the selection of the record. Dynamics CRM doesn't have the possibility to execute a workflow against a massive amount of records.

You have to script a little program which selects the records for which you would like to run the workflow and start the workflow for each of them.

See [How to run ondemand workflow over all pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907854/how-to-run-ondemand-workflow-over-all-pages/6908383#6908383)